# dividing a list with an even number of entries in half is in invalid index

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list and if it has an even number of values I'd like to find the midpoint of the two middle entries. I am doing it like this:

```
    if len(points) % 2 == 0:
        l = (points[len(points)/2][1] + points[len(points)/2 + 1][1])/2
```

However, I am getting an error which says:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not float
```

Comment: `(points[len(points)/2][1] + points[len(points)/2 + 1][1])/2` returns float probably. e.g 2.0

Comment: If you are trying to determine the median, I think the expression would be `l = (points[len(points)//2][1] + points[len(points)//2 - 1][1])/2`

Answer (score 1):

Unlike in Python 2, the `/` operator always returns a floating number in Python 3, even when the operands are all integers. You should use the floor division operator `//` instead, since list indices have to be integers:

```
l = (points[len(points) // 2][1] + points[len(points) // 2 + 1][1]) / 2
```

Comment: Worth adding that in python 2, the `/` operator when used with integers returns an integer.

Answer (score 0):

In python 3 single division gives float. Use double division instead:

```
>>> 4/2
2.0
>>> 4//2
2
```